# Go: Serve static pages (their endpoints) along side my API endpoints

Tags: go, gorilla

So I am having an issue where I can only have my API endpoints working or my static files working. I am using gorilla/mux as my router and I it might have something to do with configuring that.

I have four files that I believe matter in this situation:

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    envVars()

    router := NewRouter()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

}
```

**router.go**

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    // create new router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler

        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    return router

}
```

**routes.go**

```
var routes = Routes{

    Route{
       // TODO: Find way to render static file
       "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
    Route{
        "PostIndex",
        "GET",
        "/api/posts",
        PostIndex,
    },
    Route{
        "PostCreate",
        "POST",
        "/api/posts",
        PostCreate,
    },
}
```

**handlers.go**

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // TODO: Something to render html file
}
```

From researching I was thinking that I could maybe use a subrouter but it seems like there should be a better way about doing this. For all of my other routes I have implemented methods but for rendering an html file, I am not sure what would be put in that method.

To view the whole project, visit: https://github.com/nicholasrucci/blog

### Update

I have found [this source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gorilla-web/fBAYdk9mPVM). It is similar to what I am going through.

Comment: If you're not using templates, just read the file and write it to the responsewriter in the handler, if you're using templates, just put the static html file there and it will get served as is since it will have no placeholders/code in it to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
 code to fix error. Binding file server only to root path, leaving other routes free to be used by other handlers.

Remove the **Index** route in **routes.go** and update **router.go** like this:

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    // create new router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler

        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    router.Path("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/")))

    return router

}
```

This exposes the index.html file in the public directory under the root of your domain.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this would do the trick. When I do this I do not get a `404 not found` but I also do not get the expected file saying `"Hello World"`

Comment: My bad. I have updated the answer and this time I cloned your repo and tested that it works :)

Comment: This makes it possible to do exactly what you stated but it takes away the possibility to return JSON when `/api/posts` is hit.

Comment: darn. I have updated the solution again. Haven't tested your handlers that requires db connections but hopefully this should work better. :)

Comment: You were actually on the correct path. The order of where the path is mattered. It had to be below my api routes.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was making a template function and rendering my HTML from there.

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t := template.New("Test")
    t, err = t.Parse("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(w, t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```